# Unknown Redis command called from Lua script

Tags: redis, lua

I try to use "config get" command  to get one of redis status metrics in lua ,but get "Unknown Redis command called from Lua script", I do not know why?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return redis.call('config get','lazyfree_pending_objects')" 0
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_4e7351811a87a6961eb6fe85622dce826bbc681c): @user_script:1: @user_script: 1: Unknown Redis command called from Lua script
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return redis.call('config', 'get','lazyfree_pending_objects')" 0
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return redis.call('config', 'get','used_memory_dataset')" 0
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return redis.call('config', 'get used_memory_dataset')" 0
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_25423fef37dc24142677d59a564f5b664f9e0f45): @user_script:1: ERR CONFIG subcommand must be one of GET, SET, RESETSTAT, REWRITE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code has 2 problems.

For `config get xxx`, `config` is the command, `get` is the subcommand, and `xxx` is the configuration field. So when you call it with Lua script, you should use `redis.call('config', 'get', 'xxx')`.

If you call it as `redis.call('config get', 'xxx')`, Redis will take `config get` as the command, which is an *UNKNOWN command*. If you call it as `redis.call('config', 'get xxx')`, Redis will take `get xxx` as the subcommand, which is also invalid.

The other problem is that `lazyfree_pending_objects` and `used_memory_dataset` are NOT configuration, but system info. You should use the `INFO` command instead.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. This issue started occurring after I upgraded the python redis==2.10.5 to redis==3.5.3.

I guess it happen because of the Redis server (Linux package) version is not supported by latest python redis package.

I have upgraded linux Redis server package to 4.0.9 and it works.

Remember to restart the system.

Comment: Upgrading to a Redis server version 4.0.10 also worked for me.